# FTP Client with AppleScript support

Tags: data-synchronization, applescript, ftp

I'm looking for an FTP client with the following requirements.

- File/Folder sync
- Sftp/SSH tunnelling
- **Outstanding** AppleScript support
- Runs on Lion

The GUI interface is not overly important as it won't be the main interface used, however (and this is subjective) a better interface would be a bonus.

Comment: Why not just run shell script commands to FTP and SFTP from within the AppleScript?

Comment: That would not be my preferred solution, since it would take me too long to write and maintain, but it is feasible, just not pretty and I'd have to write a lot more script to manage retries etc

Comment: -1 Question does not show any research effort, if it's answered by a link to Transmit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried [Transmit](http://panic.com/transmit)? I think it'll do most of what you need.

Comment: I have, 5 years ago, and I do like Panic's software in general, however my needs have changed over time and I'm looking for opinions/answers on respective levels of functionality.  e.g. What makes the AS support outstanding or are they all the same

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know what your AS needs are. You might try downloading the latest version of Transmit and open up the AS dictionary in AS Editor.

Comment: With more effort you can always use `rsync, ssh, scp`

Comment: In addition to what afragen said, you can download sample Apple Scripts for Transmit from here: http://www.panic.com/transmit/d/Transmit%204%20AppleScript%20Examples.zip

Comment: @afragen sorry I really don't want to get into shell scripting if I can, it's time I lack. I can write the AS very quickly and let the program do the grunt work of the configuration and transfer handling.

Answer (score 1):

At a previous place of employment, we set up [Fetch](http://fetchsoftworks.com/fetch/) to do consistent uploads via FTP Droplets, and [Automated Uploads with it via Applescript](http://fetchsoftworks.com/fetch/tour/applescript). It supports SFTP as well, though I don't remember it being able to actually create SSH tunnels itself.

Free for 15 days, $29 license.